# is it harder to perform a stack Buffer Overflow in x86-64 than x86 system?

Tags: c, linux, architecture, buffer-overflow

I know the that the main difference between x86-64 and x86 is the memory size where x86 can only handle 32-bit instructions and x86-64 64-bit, the question becomes is it actually harder to perform a stack-based buffer overflow attack in a x86_64 system than a x86. For example, using the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char buffer[64];
   strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

what makes it actually harder to perform a buffer overflow than just adjusting the argument size for x86 and x86-64-bit architecture? .

Comment: That doesn't even compile, so I'd say it would be quite hard to perform a buffer overflow. You need something like `char buffer[5];`. So you're asking if it's harder to provide 5 bytes on an x86-64 as compared to an x86. The answer is no.

Comment: well apart from the memory size, what other security measures or efficiencies in both architecture makes it harder to perform a buffer overflow in x64 than in x86

Comment: Incidentally, the next time somebody develops a new ABI, the stack should be switched to grow from low addresses to high addresses. That way, if code overflows its buffer, it will not go into the data that records the return address. It may corrupt other local data on the stack, and that could be problematic depending on the code, but it is not the omnipresent hazard that the return address is. (And this might be further mitigated by modifying compilers to put character arrays last on the stack.) I suggested this when Apple was starting with ARM, but it was too far into tools development.

Comment: If you want to be sure the area is on the stack and not elsewhere you need to use some non-C standard features.  Nowhere in the manual of C the word `stack` appears.

If you program in POSIX, you can use `alloca` to be sure to have allocated something on the stack.

Comment: I think the real question is rather if code injection is harder on the x86_64 ABI than the previous one. In case the purpose of the buffer overflow is to replace a function call with the address to injected code, as it was done back in the days.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* harder to *overflow a buffer on the stack* when running on x86-64 than when running on x86-32.  `gets` is just as happy, on both architectures, to keep writing past the end of the buffer for as long as you supply input.

It *may* be harder to *exploit* the buffer overflow to *achieve arbitrary code execution* on x86-64, because of a number of features that x86-64 + current generation operating systems and compilers have, and x86-32 + its OSes and compilers didn't:

- [Non-executable stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection)
- [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)
- [Stack canaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries)
- [Control-flow integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_integrity)
- [String function fortification](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/enhance-application-security-fortifysource)
- et cetera

However, none of these have anything in particular to do with x86-64 having a 64-bit address space.  (Address space layout randomization is *more effective* if your address space is bigger, but it's still perfectly possible in a 32-bit space.)

Moreover, even with all of these defensive features in place and active, exploits *are still possible*.  The attacker "just" has to be cleverer.